# How to prove the mutual infomation expression in paper "Optimized Degree Distributions for Binary and Non-Binary LDPC Codes in Flash Memory"

Tags: discrete-signals, digital-communications, information-theory

Recently I met a question when I read the paper [*Optimized Degree Distributions for Binary and Non-Binary LDPC Codes in Flash Memory*](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/csl/files/presentations/Presentation_final_5_ISITA_Final6.pdf) and [*Soft Information for LDPC Decoding in Flash: Mutual-Information Optimized Quantization*](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecourtade/pdfs/WangEtAl_Globecom2011.pdf).

Both papers give the expression of $I(X;Y)$ for 3 reads, the former is:
$$I(X;Y) = H(p_{14}, p_{23}) + 1 - H(p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4)$$
and the latter is:
$$I(X;Y) = H((p_1+p_4)/2, (p_2+p_3)/2, (p_3+p_2)/2, (p_4+p_1)/2) - H(p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4)$$
I calculate both, the result seems to be same, now I want to prove both formula, but have no idea, can anyone gives some hints or proofs?